# asp.net 4, VS 2010, fileupload control, UnauthorizedAccessException, Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

asp.net 4.0, Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7, ASP.NET development server, FileUpload control

I have been battling this problem all day.  I have granted everyone full control to the directory.

I have a FileUpload control and when the code tries to SaveAs() it throws the System.UnauthorizedAccessException and I get the error:

```
{"Access to the path 'D:\FileAttachments\17' is denied."}  

_HResult = &H80070005  

Source = "mscorlib"  

StackTrace = "at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)     at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.SaveAs(String filename) ..."
```

I moved the directory out from under the website

I have granted full control to Everyone, me, Network Services, Authenticated users, System, Administrators, users, IIS_IUSRS,

Ive run attrib to remove read only access

Ive added  to the web.config

I have changed the app pool identity to Network Services - but not sure that does anything since I think VS 2010 uses its own development server.

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent returns

```
IdentifierAuthority = NTAuthority {&H5}  
AuthenticationType = "NTLM"  
Name = "mymachine\myname"
```

But in windows explorer where I try to add permissions - it does not recognize a user called "NTAuthority"

Any ideas?  thanks

(sorry about the funky formatting - stackoverflow was not letting me post the question because it thought i had code that I was not marking as code)

Comment: Dang it. The problem was actually a bad file name. Not sure why it was throwing security / permission errors when the problem was a bad / missing file name.

Answer (score 0):

Dang it.  The problem was actually a bad file name.  Not sure why it was throwing security / permission errors when the problem was a bad file name.